# Fetch data from firebase but its showing "invariant violation objects are not valid as a React child" and suggests to use array instead of objects

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to fetch data from my firebase realtime-database and view it on my react-native android app on a particular screen, every time but my code is showing **invariant violation objects are not valid as a React child. if you meant to render a collection, use array instead**

all versions are up to date

```js
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = ({
          busList: '',
          busLists: []
      })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('/').once('value', snapshot => {
        // const data = snapshot.val()
        if(snapshot.val()) {
            const initMessages = [];
            Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach(busList => initMessages.push(data[busList]));
            this.setState({
                busLists: initMessages
            })
        }
    })

    firebase.database().ref().child('/').on("child_added", snapshot =>{
        // const data = snapshot.val()
        if(snapshot.val()) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                busLists: [snapshot.val(), ...prevState.busLists]
            }))
        }
    })
  }
```

Showing 
** invariant violation objects are not valid as a React child. if you meant to render a collection, use array instead **

Comment: Could you try `busLists: [] => busLists: {}` ??

Comment: where should i put it???

Comment: This error might cause because of including an Object in JSX code. What are you returning in you render()

Comment: I am returning 
```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <View >
          <FlatList
            data = {this.state.busLists}
            renderItem = {({item}) => (
                <View>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>   
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```